# Fitting an empirical CDF curve to find exact vaue

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, cdf

I am trying to find the exact value of any number using the empirical cdf. What's the best way to get the exact value? Can I use a fitting tool and then estimate it using the fitted function?

```
[f,x] = ecdf(samples);
```

i.e How do I find the best function that fits my empirical CDF to get the exact CDF of any number I want?

These are my samples:

[image]

Comment: If this was a minimum, complete, verifiable example it would be easier to help. What are your `samples`? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Trogdor: The thing is I am implementing this in an automated way to get any type of samples (not all of them are normally distributed). So the samples can change. But I added a picture of an example of one set of samples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an approximate value of f(x) by finding the shape (σ) and location (μ) parameters that best fit the curve in a least squares sense.

Here's an "example" set of noisy "test data" with a normal distribution (similar to your sampled data):

```
>> % ytest = f(xtest, mutest, sigtest)  % sample test data
>> xtest = linspace(-10, 10, 100);  % independent variable linearly spaced
>> mutest = rand(1, 1) - 0.5;  % random location parameter
>> sigtest = 1 + rand(1, 1);  % random shape parameter
>> ytest = normcdf(xtest, mutest, sigtest) + rand(1, 100) / 10;  % distribution
mutest =
    0.2803
sigtest =
    1.6518
```

Now you can use [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) to find the shape and location parameters assuming a normal distribution. We need to provide an objective function which we want `fminsearch` to minimize so we create an an anonymous function that is the norm of the residuals between the ideal normal cumulative distribution function and the test data. The function has 2-dimensions, [μ, σ] which we pass as a vector. We also need to provide `fminsearch` with an initial guess.

```
>> % objective function with normal distribution
>> % mu(1) = location parameter (mean)
>> % mu(2) = shape parameter (standard deviation)
>> obj_func = @(mu)norm(normcdf(xtest, mu(1), mu(2)) - ytest)
>> mu0 = [0, 1];  % initial guesses for mean and stdev
>> mu = fminsearch(obj_func, mu0);
>> sigma = mu(2);  % best fit standard deviation
>> mu = mu(1)  % best fit mean
mu =
   -0.0386
sigma
    1.7399
```

Now you can predict any CDF in your empirical data using x, μ and σ using the `normcdf` function

```
>> y = normcdf(xtest, mu, sigma);
```

[image: fitting normal distribution]

[MATLAB offers many types of probability distributions.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/continuous-distributions.html) If you don't know what type of distribution your data has, and your population has **only positive values**, then one possible PDF is a [Weibull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), which has a flexible 3 parameter form: shape, scale, and location. [See "Estimate parameters of 3-parameter Weibull" on MATLAB.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/weibull-distribution.html) Then just replace [`normcdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normcdf.html) with [`wblcdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/wblcdf.html).

```
>> xtest = linspace(0, 10, 100);
>> mutest = rand(1, 1) - 0.5; % location
>> mutest
mutest = -0.35813
>> sigtest = 1 + rand(1, 2); % shape and scale
>> sigtest
sigtest =
   1.6441   1.3324
>> ytest = wblcdf(xtest-mutest, sigtest(1), sigtest(2)) + rand(1, 100) / 10;
>> % objective function with Weibull distribution
>> % mu(1) = location parameter (mean)
>> % mu(2) = scale parameter (standard deviation)
>> % mu(3) = shape parameter
>> obj_func = @(mu)norm(wblcdf(xtest-mu(1), mu(2), mu(3)) - ytest)
>> mu0 = [0, 1, 1];  % initial guesses for mean and stdev
>> mu = fminsearch(obj_func, mu0);
>> mu
mu =
  -0.85695   1.94229   1.89319
>> shape = mu(3);  % best fit shape
>> sigma = mu(2);  % best fit standard deviation
>> mu = mu(1)  % best fit mean
>> y = wblcdf(xtest-mu, sigma, shape);
```

[image: fitting weibull distribution]

Comment: But you are assuming the CDF is normal distributed, but my data is not normally distributed!

Comment: you can use a any of the [distributions functions in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/continuous-distributions.html) in your obective function - just replace `normcdf` with the desired distribution, for example for a Weibull use [`wblcdf`]http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/wblcdf.html). There is a generic [`cdf(name, ...)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdf.html) you can use and pass the name, _eg_: 'Weibull' if you prefer. Weibull is good if you don't know what probability distribution you have because it is very generic.

Comment: I replaced the normcdf with wblcdf but I only get a straight line (ones). Why?

Comment: Could be bad initial guess - try some other values instead of `[0,1]`. Or could be a poor fit (lots of noise) - there are better solvers than `fminsearch` but you'd need the [optimization toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization/) - you can get a trial. Also, the [statistical toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/) has some good regression tools - there's one called [`robustfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/robustfit.html) that is good for removing outliers.

Comment: Is it ok to rely on initial guesses for these type of optimizations using fminsearch? I will be dealing with hundreds of different sets of data (the ecdf of all of them) and I wouldn't want to have some sort of problem when trying to find the best mean and sigma that fits the ecdf in any of them...

Comment: If all of your data sets are similar then they should all have approximately the same initially guess. The issue may be `fminsearch` which uses the [Simplex or Nelder-Mead method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) which doesn't always converge. If your data is well-behaved, then you can try a gradient search method like Newton-Raphson. Try [my version on FEX from Ch 9 of numerical recipes in C](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43097-newton-raphson-solver) or [IPOPT](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2013/09/ipopt-as-non-linear-solver-for-matlab.html)

Comment: Is there a rigorous sense in which Weibull is the most generic?

Comment: Sorry @JosephGarvin and others. I mispoke. Weibull is not "most generic." It's just convenient, IMO, for representing a variety of positive PDFs. There are more flexible PDFs, but I don't think there is a "generic" PDF that is flexible enough to capture all distributions. Sorry again.